How can I make the colors in a checkerboard texture, images instead of colors?
I have a tileset from a 2D game that I want to use to texture my 3D game, without altering the tileset. So I have a wall like this that I'm trying to texture with the circled tile on the left:

My goal is to texture it like this:

But when I do the intuitive thing and plug the image into where the checkerboard color is on the shader, it looks like this:

I understand I could subdivide the wall or chop up the original tileset to achieve my goal, but I was wondering if there is any easier alternative to doing this as those methods would require overhauling the majority of my project. Ideally I'd be able to paint my models using this tileset as a palette, the checkerboard was just my best guess.

While the other guy technically answered my specific question, I found an app that does a better job of achieving what I am trying to do: https://jeiel.itch.io/sprytile

You can use the checker texture as a mask to act as factor for selecting between colors (or even complete materials, using a Mix Shader Node).
Please note that in my example the checker texture has pure black and pure white as colors, and there is a matematical corrispondence between its scale and the scale factor of the image texture mapping node.

